# Incremental encoder code

Tags: arduino-uno, rotary-encoder

can somebody tell me what`s wrong with my code, i am using it to calculate rpm using incremental encoder

```
long counter=0;
 long  rpm = 0, z =0;
 long  ini_time = 0;
long  end_time=0;




void setup(){
  attachInterrupt(0, A_RISE, RISING);

  Serial.begin(115200);
}//setup


void loop(){

    Serial.println(rpm);
}

void A_RISE(){
  counter ++;
  if (counter == 1)
    ini_time = micros();
  else if (counter>470){ //470 is ticks per revolution
    z = counter;
    rpm_counter(z);

    counter =0;
  }
}

void rpm_counter(int x){

  end_time=micros()-ini_time;
  rpm=(60*10^6)/end_time;

}
```

Comment: You need to tell us more about: what currently happens with your program, what you would expect instead.

Comment: it does not give any output in serial monitor @jfpoilpret

Comment: Can you clarify your wiring: which Arduino pin did you wire your encoder to?

Comment: i attached encoder`s channel A to digital Pin 2 on arduino which is interrupt 0.

Comment: What is weird is that you mention there is **NO** output on the serial monitor, which would mean thzn `loop()` is not even called? I suspect, your motor runs very fast and may generate too many interrupts which would prevent `loop()` from running.. Could you first try to add a delay in your loop (1 second would be fair) and see what happens?

Comment: Also, you could chnage the init order in your `setup()` to first `Serial.begin(...)`, that would give time for serial init before triggering encoder interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

**Volatile**.

Essentially any variable declared within global scope (anything you declare before you get to `setup()`) MUST have the `volatile` qualifier if you want to use it within an interrupt service routine otherwise it will not be correctly utilised/implemented/instantiated.

As your code stands, you need to add `voltatile` to all four of your global variables:

```
volatile int counter = 0;     // if you're stopping at 470, int is all you need
volatile long rpm = 0;
volatile long z = 0;          // this isn't necessary, see below!
volatile long ini_time = 0;
voltaile long end_time = 0;
```

Your ISR includes some wasteful instructions, which will increase the time it takes for the routine to complete. As @jfpoilpret suggested, you may be constantly interrupting `loop()`. Cutting the time down may solve this:

Firstly, `z = counter; rpm_counter(z);` . Pointless, if I'm honest. Why not just call rpm_counter with counter?

Secondly, `rpm_counter()` function... it doesn't use the arguement you sent! "`x`" is not used anywhere within the function, so why are you sending it?

Thirdly, even if my second point wasn't valid `rpm_counter()` doesn't really need to be a function in its own right. Unless you're going to be calling it from lots of different places, just inline the contents of the function to into `A_RISE()`:

```
else if (counter>470)
{ //470 is ticks per revolution
    end_time = micros() - ini_time;
    rpm = (60*10^6) / end_time;
    counter = 0;
}
```

That could save a great deal of execute cycles.

Comment: “any variable declared within global scope [...] MUST have the volatile qualifier if you want to use it within an interrupt service routine”. This is incorrect. The `volatile` qualifier is needed if the variable is going to be used both in the ISR **and** in the main program. OTOH, if the variable is only used inside the ISR, it should be static local rather than global.

Comment: Could this be what's wrong with the code in my question here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/88812/variable-getting-set-to-zero-nondeterministically?noredirect=1#comment202751_88812